# Запись неверных данных в БД SQL

Tags: python, telegram-bot, sqlite

Делаю финансового бота и мне необходимо записать данные о доходе пользователя через тг бота. Вроде написал ф-цию, но почему-то записывает вообще непонятные данные...

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=["add_salary"]) 
def zp_add(message):
    msg = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, '''Введите ваш текущий доход: ''')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, zp_add2)



def zp_add2(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Данные были успешно добавлены!')
    db = sqlite3.connect("finothc.db")
    cur = db.cursor()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO finansi (Доход) VALUES(?)", [message.from_user.id])
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вот ваши введенные 
данные\n{}'.format(message.text))
    db.commit()
    db.close()
```

Допустим я введу 20000, а в БД впишется 745764314. Я так понимаю это id сообщения и как тогда исправить?

Comment: `cur.execute("INSERT INTO finansi (Доход) VALUES(?)", [message.from_user.id])` вот в этой строке вы что пишите в базу ? как по мне, `message.from_user.id` как раз и есть id пользователя, скрипт пишет ровно то, что вы ему указали

Comment: Ну да, этот код пишет в базу `id` пользователя, как вы в коде и указали.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO finansi (Доход) VALUES(?)", [message.text])
```

В общем, все верно выполнялось. Просто не те значения я пытался ввести

Answer (score 2):

Попробуй так

```
def zp_add2(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Данные были успешно добавлены!')
    db = sqlite3.connect("finothc.db")
    cur = db.cursor()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO finansi (Доход) VALUES(?)", [message.text])
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вот ваши введенные 
данные\n{}'.format(message.text))
    db.commit()
    db.close()
```

Comment: Так тоже работает, но мне user_id в этом случае просто не нужен. Задумка в другом. Спасибо большое

Comment: `INSERT ...VALUES ... WHERE` ??  Насколько я помню, условие может применяться только когда выполняется `INSERT INTO .. SELECT WHERE`

Comment: @NowhereMan действительно